# ReactJs problema al importar librería

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un problema hace varias horas con una importación. Ya descargué `@material-ui/icons` y `@material-ui/core`
pero sigo recibiendo el mismo error

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore'

Answer (score 1):

La librería MUI se actualizó hace poco tiempo a la versión 5.
Fijate en la documentación correspondiente a la versión que estás utilizando, que estes usando los imports correspondientes.

Si publicaras un bloque de tu código quizás se pueda identificar más fácilmente el problema.

Saludos.

Comment: messirvio amigo gracias